# a blocking operation was interrupted by a call to wsacancelblockingcall

Tags: c#, sockets

I am using a windows service to communicate with a device using Udp socket. In the constructor of the service, I have the following code

```
public Service1()
    {

        try
        {
            EventLog eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();

            eventLog1.Source = "Alert Control Service";
            eventLog1.Log = "Application";

            //InitializeComponent();
            //TextBox settings
            //Wire-up the EventHandler

            //Create the UdpClient
            server = new UdpClient(port);

            serverForAdam = new UdpClient(6768);
            //Define a Receive point
            receivePoint = new IPEndPoint(new IPAddress(ip), port);
            IPAddress adam1 = IPAddress.Parse("172.16.2.252");
            adamReceivePoint = new IPEndPoint(adam1, 1025);
            string channel = "";



            //read alarm configuration from database

            RegistryKey baseKey = null;

            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
            {

                 baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
            }
            else
            {
                 baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
            }


            RegistryKey myKey = baseKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\AlarmConfig", true);

            if (myKey == null) 
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("No AlarmConfig Registry key");
            }

            string regString = (string)myKey.GetValue("database");
            string decryptString = Crypto.DecryptStringAES(regString, "1234");
            SQLConn.ConnectionString = decryptString;
            SQLConn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("c:\\error.txt");

            // write a line of text to the file
            tw.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            // close the stream
            tw.Close();
        }

    }
```

Which will write a line :
a blocking operation was interrupted by a call to wsacancelblockingcall in the error.txt

so what is the reason for it. I have try to run the service as normal windows application. It is ok, the message does not exist. Please help.

Comment: You don't appear to do any listening or otherwise start a thread to send anything.  If you don't create a thread and start it, then I should think the service will just stop?

Comment: This message happens when the UDPClient is blocking (will not move in a loop to avoid useless loops) and you call UDPClient.Close() to terminate the UDPClient and exit out of loop, but this still gives this error message.. I found no way around it.. There is no UDPClient.StopBlocking command.